# Problem logging in on a StackExchange site

Tags: support, login

This is about logging in on another StackExchange site, but I think the problem applies to any SE site, including this one.

Long time ago I created an account on math.stackexchange, but I haven't been there for a while. I used to login with my OpenID account, but that option seems to have been dropped. When I login with my Google account I create a new account. They suggest I can merge a new account with an existing one, but then I have to be able to login to the existing account in the first place. Looks like I'm stymied. How do I get in again?

Answer (score 1):

If you flag for a moderator from your new account on one of your old account posts explaining the issue and we can easily verify such a thing we can perform the merge without much more then a few more button clicks. Please try to set things to be similar between the accounts, same email(which is hidden to all but moderators and developers) and name. This is the preferred method as the devs are busy. [There is a very detailed post explaining that here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/73801/152553).

Your other other option is to use the contact us at the bottom of the screen and explain your issue in the email with both of your accounts link, specifying the primary. This will go to the SE overlords and be corrected. This will not require rights to flag a post, but this does use the Dev teams time, which I would prefer is spent on new features, the other method can be handled by moderators.

Comment: Thanks. Silly question: On my new account page I don't see any way to flag for a moderator. I can see a "contact us" link, but that's an e-mail link, I'd like it more direct.

Comment: I think I now remember that, you can flag one of the posts your old account had, that is how I normally see those flags, they are pretty rare.

Comment: I didn't see any flag links anywhere until I asked a new question. Probably due to lack of rep. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Alternatively, you can always email team+math@stackexchange.com (from 'contact us' in the footer) regardless of your rep.  That goes straight to the Stack Exchange team and they're also able to fix this.

Comment: @stevenvh, if my method is not easily followed due to rep issues please do as kevin suggests, I will edit post.

Comment: I managed to flag, and got an answer by mail. They have to think about it due to my high rep here. :-) Thanks, both of you.

Comment: @steven: I guess they're afraid you're going to game the rep system on another site, using the loophole you found here where you write a bunch of good answers people like.

Comment: @OlinLathrop, I warned them of his plan on that to avoid him gaming the system on two different sites!

Comment: @Kortuk - You don't have to fear for that. If I try to read what those mathematicians post there I can't understand any of it :-)

Comment: @Kortuk -  Besides, what gaming! Olin and Russell have answered as many questions here as I have (about a thousand), and they have been around for a shorter time!

Comment: @Kevin - "you can always email team+math@stackexchange.com". Thanks. I thought flagging would be more direct. With all that interactivity, SMS and such, it sometimes looks like e-mail is 2012's snail mail ;-)

Comment: @stevenvh, flagging is considered the preferred method. The gaming the system by writing high quality answers is a joke.

Comment: @Kortuk - Yeah, no problem. Like you said yourself: Europeans are a bit slower (868MHz) ;-)

Comment: @Kortuk - While I can't flood math.stackexchange with answers I could do so with questions! I don't understand a word of what those guys say. You would think that, as an engineer, you at least know *some* math. Not! :-(